# extending query timeout settings

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, timeout

I have a WPF application that directly communicates with a MS SQL 2008 database.

In the connection string, I have explicitly set the connection time out to be "Connect Timeout=6000", which should give me ten minutes.

I see that my application gives me a timeout error in just a little more than a minute. How can I ensure that I am given 10 minutes to complete my query?

I don't know if there's something missing in my connection string setup or database call, or whether this should be configured from the MS SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different timeout value for query.  If you are using `SqlCommand`, you can set your timeout value using [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I just checked similar questions here and there's something written about a CommandTimeout. Let me try that first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting 'Connect Timeout' in your connection string only applies to the opening of your connection to the database. In your query method, you need to set the timeout on your DbCommand object to your connection's timeout.